# On change method Angular2 and Javascript

Tags: jquery, html, angular

In my application I have two select and I want that when I change one select others will change automatically and I want to detect while change second one.Below one first. When I change this one

```
 <select class="diffex"[(ngModel)]="isdif">
      <option class="dif" value="0">All</option>
      <option class="dif" value="1">Not Equals</option>
 </select>
```

below one will change automatically

```
<th class="text-center" >
     <select class="diffex2"[(ngModel)]="isdif">
          <option class="dif" value="0">All</option>
          <option class="dif" value="1">Not Equals</option>
     </select>
</th>
```

with angular I can do it. There is no problem here.Problem is below one. I want to detect if it changes. Value is changing but below code is not working. I want to see hello in console when I want to change first select.

```
  $('.diffex2', this.header()).on('keyup change bind', function () {
                console.log("hello");})
```

Where do I make mistake?

Comment: Why are you mixing Angular and jQuery? I'd recommend reading Angular's guidance on using forms, see e.g. https://angular.io/guide/forms.

Comment: I use datatable in angular, for individual colum search datatable use jquery .

Comment: @ÇağrıTaçyıldız there is already many fork of datatable which work with angular try that http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `(ngModelChange)="changeHandler()"` to run code when your select has changed.

```
 <select class="diffex" [(ngModel)]="isdif" (ngModelChange)="handleChange($event)">
     <option class="dif" value="0">All</option>
     <option class="dif" value="1">Not Equals</option>
 </select>
```

Then, in your Typescript:

```
 handleChange(newModelValue) {
     console.log(newModelValue);
 }
```

I don't recommend using jquery with Angular -- whenever your tempted to do so remember that Angular probably already has a solution.

Comment: @Vikas, your edit is slightly incorrect. The event passed into ngModelChange is the value -- not the HTML element. Also, by removing the parens from the ngModel the two way binding with the value in the controller is broken -- it would change behavior.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a one-way binding to `ngModel` with `[]` syntax, changing the value of the domain model in the component class will set the value in the view. If you have a two-way binding with `[(ngModel)]` syntax (also known as 'banana-box syntax'), the value in the UI will always be synced back to the domain model in your class as well.
The `[(ngModel)]` syntax can only set a data-bound property. If you need to do something more or something different, you can write the expanded form.

```
<select #ref class="diffex"[ngModel]="isdif" (ngModelChange)="ondataChange(ref.value)">
      <option class="dif" value="0">All</option>
      <option class="dif" value="1">Not Equals</option>
 </select>
```

The `ngModel` data property sets the element's value property and the `ngModelChange` event property listens for changes to the element's value
Apart from this  Pass [Template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars) instead of passing entire `event` [Passing $event is a dubious practice](https://angular.io/guide/user-input#passing-event-is-a-dubious-practice)

In your component

```
ondataChange(value) {
             this.isdif=value;
    }
```